# populate a table view using an array from core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, core-data

Am try to populate my table from core data and it give an error at this line

```
Tips *tipy = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

here is my .m file

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [arr count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    Tips *tipy = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    cell.textLabel.text = [tipy tipdescription];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tipy.tipnumber stringValue];

    return cell;
}
```

app and arr is declared in the .h file as and also synthesized in the .m file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AppDelegate *app;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSArray *arr;
```

Comment: what error do you have ? did you "#import Tips" in your file ? Did you synthesized the property ? if so you shoukd write "self.arr" instead of arr

Answer (score 5):

As moxy said, you should write `self.arr` instead of `arr`. You have set `@property(nonatomic, assaign) NSArray *arr;` Did you synthesized those properties? Be sure to do that. And Try `@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arr;` instead of `@property(nonatomic, assaign) NSArray *arr;`. The assaign does not increase the retain count thus there is a chance that the value can be autoreleased. Don't forget to release the arr in dealloc to avoid memory leak.

Comment: thanks alot. the problem was coz i did not use retain in my array

Comment: if this answer helped you, accept it. you should accept answers according to [Stackoverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, because there's not enough code to check, but `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `executeFetchRequest:error:` does return autoreleased `NSArray` and your property `arr` is defined as `assign`, not `strong`/`retain` => your `NSArray` is released and `arr` points to trash. Maybe this is the cause, but as I said, there's not enough code to be sure.